# Folding square puzzle

Tags: geometry, puzzle

This problem is framed by me. Here I have posted to let others see the beauty of mathematics.

> A square is folded as shown. $3$ squares are inscribed in $3$ triangles are formed. Area of blue and green squares are $2\,\mathrm{cm}^2$ and $3\,\mathrm{cm}^2$, respectively. Find the area of the red square.
>
> [image: Interesting geometry problems]

Note: this question is not incorrect or incorrectly stated.

Comment: What have you tried towards solving the problem?

Comment: Actually, this problem is framed by me. Here I have posted to let's other see the beauty of mathematics.

Comment: @SwaroopDora: It's a nice puzzle, but posting questions to which you already know the answer is not appropriate for Math.SE. At the very least, you should include in the body of the question a disclaimer that you don't actually need help, so that people don't waste their valuable time trying to assist you.

Comment: I will take care next.

Answer (score 2):

[image: A puzzle of squares]

Let

- $\ell$ be the side of the big square $ABCD$.
- $x = \sqrt{2}$, $y = \sqrt{3}$ be the sides of the two green squares.
- $z$ be the side of the red square.

Choose a coordinate system where $A$ is the origin and $B$ lies on +ve $x$-axis.
In this coordinate system, square $ABCD$ becomes $[0,\ell]^2$.

Reflect everything across the fold line (the cyan dashed line).
Square $ABCD$ get mapped to square $A'B'C'D'$ while the red square get mapped to the square $[\ell-z,\ell]^2$.

Let $E = (x,x)$, $F = (\ell-y,y)$, $G = (\ell-z,\ell-z)$ be the contact points
of the two green and new red square with square $A'B'C'D'$.

Since $DF$ and $EG$ are line segments whose end points lie on opposite sides
of square $A'B'C'D'$ and $DF \perp EG$, they are equal in length,
i.e. $|DF| = |EG|$. This leads to
$$(\ell - y)\sqrt{2} = (\ell - x - z)\sqrt{2} \quad\implies\quad
z = y - x$$
As a result, the area of the original red square equal to
$$z^2 = (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^2 = 5-2\sqrt{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

All segment lengths are marked in the diagram. Match below the total side lengths of the square,

$$\begin{align}
L = & \sqrt2 (\sec a+\csc a+\tan a+1) \\
= & \sqrt2 (1+\cot a) + \sqrt3(\tan a+1) \\
= & \sqrt3(\sec a+\csc a) + x(\cot a+1)\\
\end{align}$$

Solve for $a$ from the first two expressions to get $\tan\frac{a}2 = \frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}-1$ and then plug it into the last two expressions to otain
 $x =a-b\tan(\frac\pi4 - \frac a2) = \sqrt3 - \sqrt2$. Thus, the area of the red square is $$x^2 = 5-2\sqrt6$$