# Puzzle: wonderful equilateral triangle vs angle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Two equilateral triangles and two congruent rectangles.
Find the angle marked red?

Comment: If this is another puzzle devised by you, *please say so in the question*, as I suggested after [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3632652/409).

Comment: Since your quadrilateral is a rhombus, it's easy to see that the dashed line is on the other diagonal. Bearing in mind $\color{red}{\text{diagonals of a rhombus are perpendicular to each other}}$, the dashed line must lie on the altitude perpendicular to the drawn diagonal. Therefore, the marked triangle is isosceles with angles $2\times 30^{\circ}$ and $120^{\circ}$.

Comment: Also, you can observe $\color{brown}{\text{the mirror symmetry with respect to the other diagonal}}$.

Comment: You can also draw a the altitude from the **obtuse** angle of the rhombus and observe the same diagonal of a trapezoid to convice yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This looks almost too easy:

[image]

The answer is $120^\circ$.

Comment: +1 yup, too easy.